# Objective-C Testing values in a range

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an objective-c question. I have an app that detects the rotation of the iOS device. I want to be able to have a timer started when the value is between two ranges. Basically if the rotation is between 0.1 and -0.1 then the timer will trigger.

I have tried while loops, for loops and I'm sure it is something simple I need to implement.

Thanks in advance for the suggestions!

-Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your comment, it looks like you might have the logic reversed.

You had:

```
if (rotationValue >= 0.1 && rotationValue <= -0.1) {
   // doSomethingHere;
}
```

If you're looking for when the "rotation is between 0.1 and -0.1 then the timer will trigger", then you'd want:

```
if (rotationValue >= -0.1 && rotationValue <= 0.1) {
   // doSomethingHere;
}
```

(I switched the order around, putting the negative on the left and the positive on the right, as that seems more logical to me, but anyway).

Or you could do:

```
if (ABS(rotationValue) <= 0.1) {
   // doSomethingHere;
}
```

Comment: NSGod, you are a god! Thank you. I knew it was something simple, just couldn't get my head around it! Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 0):

Take a [`NSTImer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/)

if you are entering that range (just store a bool for that) you create a new timer using

`[NSTimer scheduledTimer...]` and if you are existing that region you will need to `invalidate` your timer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know how to create the timer, but not test when the rotation value falls between the range of 0.1 and -0.1... my original logic was to do this: if(rotationValue >= 0.1 && rotationValue <= -0.1) { doSomethingHere; }

Comment: As NSGod suggested, the expression `(rotationValue >= 0.1 && rotationValue <= -0.1)` will never be true.  A numeric value can never simultaneously be greater than 0.1 and less than -0.1.